# What does //= require mean?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

What does the "//= require bootstrap/affix" in [this .js code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js) mean?

```
//= require bootstrap/affix
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
//= require bootstrap/carousel
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/tab
//= require bootstrap/transition
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/tooltip
//= require bootstrap/popover
```

Comment: Does it have any special meaning for any tool or something? If this file is just all comments, then you have this file?

Comment: I see this in most Ruby on Rails projects.
It is used to include other JS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the rails [`manifest` system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) in the Rails asset pipeline:

> In JavaScript files, Sprockets directives begin with //=. In the above
>   case, the file is using the require and the require_tree directives.
>   The require directive is used to tell Sprockets the files you wish to
>   require. Here, you are requiring the files jquery.js and jquery_ujs.js
>   that are available somewhere in the search path for Sprockets. You
>   need not supply the extensions explicitly. Sprockets assumes you are
>   requiring a .js file when done from within a .js file.

It basically means when you `precompile` your assets, all the files you call using the `//=` directive will be compiled into the `application.js` file for you

You should [read up about it here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)

Answer (score 3):

I assume it is in Rails application (or taken from it), in which case, `//=` is a directive for the javascript manifest files, to include the specified file.

you can read more about it here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html